# Multiple users connecting to AWS EC2 via SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was trying to organize how a developer could connect via SSH to an AWS instance that I had launched as an administrator. I notice in the documentation that it says:

you'll need the fully-qualified path of the .pem file for the key pair that you specified when you launched the instance.

Does this mean one can only SSH into an instance that one had launched ? I'd like to just leave the instance running and have others able to SSH in to install software and configure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to add new users/developers to an AMAZON EC2 linux instance and give them unique SSH Key access:

Say you are creating "user": Create a key on your own machine by entering the following:

```
ssh -keygen -b 1024 -f user -t dsa
```

Don't use a paraphrase -- just hit enter.
You should now have two files compiled: user and user.pub

`chmod 600 user.pub`

Now transfer the public key file (user.pub) from your computer to the server. For example let us use the /tmp/ directory.
Now SSH into your server using an account with root access, you will now need to create the user and also create the necessary files and ownership for you to use the key you just created:

```
# sudo su (if needed)
# useradd -c "firstname lastname" user
# cd /home/user
# mkdir .ssh
# chmod 700 .ssh
# chown user:user .ssh
# cat /tmp/user.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
# chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
# chown user:user .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Once you've done this, exit out back to your own machine, then try to SSH using the new credential and user account you've created:

`ssh -i user.pem user@ec2-your-instance-name.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Could you explain where the user.pem file comes from. Do I need to also go into the AWS console and create this same new user and download a .pem file ? Thanks.

Comment: user.pem file is generated in the instance when you run the keygen command

Comment: as you said above: user and user.pub are generated. I just now copied the user file to user.pem and I can sign on using ssh. Thanks. I'm not clear on the relationship between AWS users via the console and this linux created users. I don't see this new linux user in the IAM area of the console. Can I link them and assign access rights ?

Comment: @user1069528 So this linux created users will have access to the server and not the AWS console untill you create there accounts in AWS console. Also you cannot link them from the server side.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance, you can specify a key at launch time.  What ends up happening is that AWS takes the public key associated with the key pair you created, and puts it into authorized_keys in /home/ec2-user/.ssh/.

So, if this is a one-time thing, you could provide the private key (the .pem file you downloaded when you created the key) to the user that needs access.

If this is an on-going issue - i.e. you will be creating lots of instances and having lots of different people who need to access them - then you need a better solution, but you'll have to figure out what your requirements are.

Some potential solutions would be to get public keys from your users, add them to an instance, and then create an AMI from that instance.  Use that AMI to launch future instances.  You could also put users public keys into S3, and have a script that pulled them down when the instance was created & either added them to authorized_keys or created individual users.  You could pull users keys from IAM if all your users have IAM accounts.  Or you could use a directory & configure your instance to use that for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

One way to setup user management is

1. Ask all the users to create their own public-private key.
2. Everyone shares/copy/checkin their public key at some location where we can run rsync server to expose all the public keys
3. On the server, fetch all these keys from rsync server and run a usercreate command.

Another way is, have a base image in AWS with users already created with their public key in authorized_keys. And use this image to create new instances.